# I am getting the answer 0.0 of this java code.why I am getting this?

Tags: java

```
public class Foo
 { 
    public static void main(String[] args) { 
    System.out.println(Math.min(Double.MIN_VALUE, 0.0d));
 } 
}
```

I am getting 0.0 answer why?
what is the reason behind this?`
In the another post it explains Double.MIN_VALUE is the least positive value 
but here my result is 0.0 which is neither positive nor negative according to English language.

Comment: Commenting on your edit, you are printing out `Math.min(Double.MIN_VALUE, 0.0d)`, so which is smaller, `Double.MIN_VALUE` or 0?

Comment: Ok, bro now I understand why it is so. Print 0.0 because of Double.MIN_VALUE is greater than 0